# convert dynamic number of rows in sql to fixed number of columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I need to create a specific report in SQL server. Let’s assume that there are two table named A and B. I create a temp table from A and B, named TMP. TMP can have 0 to 10 records (it is depends on where clues value, which enter by user). I need to convert these records to columns in final report. But due to the dynamic number of TMP records and following that, dynamic number of columns, I can’t use a simple PIVOT.

I reviewed some of the similar questions but the answers was not helpful in my situation.

Can I create an empty temp table with fix number of columns (10) and fill that with PIVOT of TMP? If not, what is your solution?

Comment: What's producing the final report? Is it some form of report building tool or application? It may be easier to do the pivot *there* rather than in SQL.

Comment: I have to use SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not all clear, but my magic crystall ball tells me, that you might be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT o.[name]
          ,CONCAT('Column',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.object_id)) AS ColumnName
    FROM sys.objects o
    --WHERE ...
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX([name]) FOR ColumnName IN(Column1,Column2,Column3 /*add as many as you need*/)
) p;
```

The idea in short:

The `SELECT` will return a list of values. In this example I used `sys.objects` and return the object's `name`. This list's row count will depend on the `WHERE` clause, but should not exceed 10 (in your case).

In the example above, I use `CONCAT()` to compute a *column name* by adding `ROW_NUMBER()`.

This computed ColumnName can be used in `PIVOT`.

If your list is shorter than 10 rows, you will simply get NULLs.

But you must be carefull, if your list might be longer than 10. In this case, the rows >10 will be invisible without any notice...

Comment: tnx a lot. It was so helpful